# Segmentation violation detected - matlab

Tags: matlab, segmentation-fault, matlab-figure

I get the error `Segmentation violation detected` in Matlab 7.12.0.635 (R2011a) (on Ubuntu 12.10) whenever I try to save a figure as jpg or png. I can save a figure as .fig, though...

What can I do to fix this problem? Have you encountered this problem?

Comment: No. I'm on a single monitor.

Comment: Are you using `print` or `saveas` or clicking with the mouse on `File > Save as...`?

Comment: I am using Save As. I only got this error now. I've used Save as two weeks ago on the same computer...

Comment: weird...did any updates recently?

Comment: What does `print('filename', '-djpeg', '-zbuffer')` do?

Comment: Looks like it saves the figure as jpg. At least now I can save it. I wonder what's the problem with the GUI method?

Comment: Looks like a problem with the default figure renderer. What's `get(gcf, 'renderer')` say? `OpenGl`?

Comment: Can you post the complete crash dump?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19304/discussion-between-beni-bogosel-and-rody-oldenhuis)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved by changing the default renderer to `zbuffer`. Add this line to the `startup.m` file:

> `set(0, 'DefaultFigureRenderer', 'zbuffer');`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by installing matlab-support package,

```
 sudo apt-get install matlab-support
```

Comment: I believe you mean "sudo apt-get install matlab-support", but yeah, it appears as if that fixed the issue for me too.

Comment: Yeap, If you like edit my solution. I will approve it.